# How can I prove that if a game is finite, then it always has a winning strategy for every node in a graph.

Tags: predicate-logic, game-theory, first-order-logic

Any node can be the starting node and the game is finite (i.e no possible infinite loop). I need to show that for such game there exists a winning strategy for either verifier or the falsifier for every starting node.

Comment: Think about using induction on the depth of the graph.

Comment: My idea is to do it recursively. For every leaf nodes, either Verifier and falsifier has the winning strategy. Now for the nodes in n-1 level, we can say the node leading to winning node(in leaf) respective winner from leaf has the winning strategy. But I don't to how to formulate it or even if it is complete.

Comment: Can we be sure that draws are impossible ?

Comment: That's what I need to prove, and yes because the game is finite one has to win after n moves.